# top not showing the memory usage of cat

Tags: cat, file-copy, clipboard

I wanted to generate some waste file of 50 GB. so i wrote this

```
eightnoteight@mr:~/ while true; do
> cat txt >> tmp
> cat tmp >> txt
> done
```

and when i ran top,watch to observe. I noticed that in top the memory consumption of cat is 0.0

If cat is not consuming my memory who is doing the work? (Is it direct kernel calls?)

[image: cat memory consumption]

Comment: on a side note, but related to your initail goal: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G count=50 > mytmpfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting misled by the rounding in the %MEM column.  If you note the VIRT and RSS column, they report the amount of virtual memory and resident memory used.  In both cases you can see that they are non-zero.

Virtual memory is the amount of virtual memory the process has, including shared libraries and pages that have been swapped out. Resident memory (RSS) is the amount of non-swapped physical memory that the process has in use.

Because `cat` is a small executable with a simple job and low memory requirements, the bytes of memory it takes up rounds to 0.0 on your system with 4GB of main memory.

Your instinct isn't far off, however, your kernel is doing most of the work that is actually involved in writing the file to disk.

Comment: does this mean that appending some 4 GB through cat appends in very small chunks (~ 10 MB)?

Comment: @mr.eightnoteight Correct.  If I run `cat file >other_file` where file is 4GB, cat is /not/ reading all 4GB into memory and then writing it all.  If you use the `strace` utility, you can see that it is reading a chunk, then writing a chunk.  On my system, cat read 1MB at a time.

Comment: If cat read it all in then read it out, then a 32bit system could not read a 4GB file, so a 50GB file would be way out. But it can. Also it would waste a lot of memory, imagine on a system with low RAM reading in a file that is swapped out. Then swapping it in as it is  written out.